# How to carry data of a variable to the rest of the same page?

Tags: php, mysqli

It really is easy for me to do it in the following way:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id_product = $row['id_courses'];
        $product = $row['product'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $subtitle = $row['subtitle'];
        $price = $row['price'];
    }
}
```

Then later only print the value of the variable on any part of the page as follows:

```
echo $product;
```

**How can I do the same with an object-oriented query?**

> like the previous query, this query also works, I perform the same procedure and print the value correctly:

```
echo $product;
```

but it is correct that this code `while ($stmt->fetch()) {}` is left empty in the following query

```
$stmt->bind_param("i",$active);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result( $id_product,$product,$subtitle,$price);

      while ($stmt->fetch()) {

      }
```

Comment: I dont understand the question. It's the same, There is no difference. The only difference between the procedural api and the oo api is that you get to call fetch on the stmt instance instead of passing it to some function.

Comment: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {print_r($row);//check output and do accordingly, or show us the output}`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I think that is the answer OP is looking, creating the `$row` variable in the 2nd code

Comment: @Swellar  i hope so. Let OP say something regarding this

Comment: @Swellar if I have tried but it is correct that this `while ($stmt->fetch()) {}` is left empty

Comment: @Swellar if it works but is it correct that it is empty or not?

Comment: What do you mean by empty? If it works, have you tried creating the variables the same as the 1st code?

Comment: `if it works`-> why if? test it.   `but is it correct that it is empty or not?`->apply empty checkes there

Comment: @Swellar You told me that if I had tried this way `echo $product;` if I tried it works but it is correct that this `while ($stmt->fetch()) {}` is empty

Comment: @Swellar example in the first query has data `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id_product = $row['id_courses'];` but in the second it does not

Comment: Have you tried `while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {$id_product = $row['id_courses'];}`? Then `echo $id_product`?

Comment: @Swellar update my question, I have not tried it that way I will prove that but in the second query if it works as well as this only I do not know if it is correct to be empty without data, I am learning oriented objects and I still do not understand well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of `while`.

It was useless with your old approach and become harmful with second one.

You have to understand that this while thing is not some obligatory part of the database interaction but the way to get **multiple** rows. But since you are fetching only one row, you shouldn't use while at all.

Your first code block should be

```
$result = mysqli_query(...);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id_product = $row['id_courses'];
...
```

and the second one as well

```
$stmt->bind_param("i",$active);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result( $id_product,$product,$subtitle,$price);
$stmt->fetch();
```

in the first block you saved variables manually inside while, and thet's why they were available outside the loop. But in the second they are populated directly by fetch() method and therefore it makes them all empty on the last iteration when no more data left.

Comment: Thanks is that I'm new in object-oriented, in more than one product works the same?

Comment: "while" has absolutely nothing to do with "object-oriented". your trouble is coming not from whatever "object-oriented", but from the fact that mysqli prepared statements are inconvenient to use at whole. Better use PDO instead.